# Sails autodelete a resouce I added in layout

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm using Select2 in a sails project (https://select2.org/getting-started/installation). For that I added the following lines in my layout.ejs

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

But when I run the application with the command `sails lift` the two lines are automatically deleted from the layout.ejs.
I know it's not the editor (I'm using vscode) because I test that looking for the problem. Do you know what I can do to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sails uses Grunt to generate files and automatically add resources into layout.

Scripts are inserted between `<!--SCRIPTS-->` and `<!--SCRIPTS END-->`

Styles are inserted between `<!--STYLES-->` and `<!--STYLES END-->`

So if you add resources manually between these tags, they will be deleted by Grunt.

See https://sailsjs.com/documentation/anatomy/tasks/config/sails-linker.js for more informations

Comment: I have to add the resources locally to the folder assets/dependencies, automatically after running sails lift that resources are added to the layout.